# Is it recommended to remove Row from DataTable while in Foreach loop?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

As the title says, is it recommended to remove Data Row from Data Table while in foreach loop?

Here what I got so far -

```
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                billObj.callerID = Convert.ToInt64(row["callerID"]);
                billObj.bsRespond = billObj.chargePhone(billObj);
                if (!billObj.bsRespond.StartsWith("OK"))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Frankly, I'd say no because I can't find reasons to recommend using DataTable in most cases. But also: indeed, you can't remove while iterating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not, you're modifying the collection that you are iterating over.  Your program will blow up when you attempt to remove the row there.  You cannot modify the collection while using an enumerator that was created for it [otherwise it will throw an `InvalidOperationException()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx).

Comment: So, should I make a List and store the rows to be removed and remove them from the DataTable?

Comment: Do you have a need for the table with these rows omitted after the loop?

Comment: @YeMyatAung: That would certainly be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Induster Yes. I need to use that table later.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use another enumerator?

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray())
{

...

}
```

Comment: I'd use `ToList()` instead however.  Only use `ToArray()` if you specifically need an array (e.g., to pass into a method).

Comment: @JeffMercado The goal of the code is to make an immutable set, and Array reflects this more clearly.

Comment: Arrays are still mutable... They're just fixed in length. It's better to use lists since the contents only need to be copied once. Since arrays are fixed in length, they cannot be dynamically resized and use a list as an intermediate storage.

Comment: @JeffMercado Array enumerators cannot mutate - you shouldn't have mutation here. List uses `Buffer<T>` which uses an array under the covers. Many Array vs List wars have been fought before - it's ultimately just a matter of preference. :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this, if there is no "RemoveAll(predicate)", is to keep a list of removals (here generalised to any type):

```
var remove = new List<SomeType>();
foreach(var row in source) {
    if(condition) remove.Add(row);
}
foreach(var obj in remove) {
    source.Remove(obj);
}
```

However, when available, the:

```
source.RemoveAll(row => condition);
```

approach is simpler.